# Should I really prefer to use std_logic type to write sythesizable VHDL?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

Recently while reading a Xilinx's ["Synthesis and Simulation Design Guide"](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/sim.pdf), I came over a passage (p. 40) where they recommended the usage of the `std_logic` data type.

While I understand the power of the `std_logic` (e.g. its ability to represent the special signal states), I come from CS background and on my previous ventures with VHDL I also liked the expresiveness of its type system (e.g. ability to constrain integers, etc.).

Should I really prefer to use the `std_logic`? I can see its usefulness for I/O or top-level declarations but I would like to use more "high level" data inside the FPGA.

Comment: If it interfaces out to something unknown...you probably should. If it interfaces out to something specific that I made, I just use integers if required because it's a pain otherwise.

Comment: Or switch to Verilog and you save yourself a world of typing and conversions (Now I am waiting for the storm, to hit.. :-)

Comment: @Oldfart While I want to learn Verilog, currently I am working on a project that must be written in VHDL. Plus, I like the strong type system of VHDL :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For external signals that drives pins, `std_logic` should be used (and derivatives such as `std_logic_vector`, `unsigned`, `signed`). Alternatively `bit`

For internal signals, `integer` with range bounds, `record`, `boolean`, enumerated types, even `character` are synthesisable.

`Time` is not synthesisable except for calculating integer constants, floating point `real` also only for constants.